# How to point to a different Controller of a Model in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have one Model class named 'Name' and one Controller class named 'Controller1'. I have created a form using 'Name' model which is by default pointing to 'names' controller as per default naming convention of cakephp. But i want it to point to 'Controller1' controller..

I've replace this code:-

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Name'); ?>
```

with this one to see if it works:-

```
<?php 
     echo $this->Form->create('Name',array('controller'=>'Controller1', 
    'action'=>'view')); 
?>
```

But it is not working and is pointing to 'names' controller only. 
[image]

How can i point it to 'Controller1' instead of 'names' controller?

More details:- 
Model (Name.php):-

```
class Name extends AppModel{
    public $useTable = "tbl_names";
}
```

Controller (Controller1Controller.php):-

```
class Controller1Controller extends AppController
{    
    public function index(){

    }

    public function view($id){
        $name ='';
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $name = $this->request->data('name');
            if($name==="xyz"){
                $this->redirect('http://www.google.com');
            }else{
                $this->Save($this->request->data);
                $this->request->data['name']= 'Nice';
            }
        }
        return $id;
    }

    // Save to database if entered name is other than 'xyz'
    private function Save($data){
        $this->Name->create();
    }

    public function viewname($id,$name){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set url key to pass crontroller and action values.

```
echo $this->Form->create(false, array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'add'),
    'id' => 'RecipesAdd'
));
```

See [FormHelper > Options for create()](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)